# increment directory name in bash

Tags: linux, bash, date

I have a bash script whereby i'd like to create a directory with the date and an incremental number upon every boot using date

```
 DATE=$(date +"%d%m%Y")
```

I'd like the output to be 300514-1 then after a reboot 300514-2 and so on but the files need to be stored into that directory that was created ie

```
SAVEDIR=/home/files/$DATE-*
```

Comment: If you want only the last two digits of the year, you need to use a lowercase `y` in the format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

date=$(date +"%d%m%Y")
n=1

# Increment $N as long as a directory with that name exists
while [[ -d "/home/files/${date}-${n}" ]] ; do
    n=$(($n+1))
done

mkdir "/home/files/${date}-${n}"
```

Note that the script isn't safe against race conditions, meaning you cannot use it in an environment where many concurrent processes calling the script at the same time.

Comment: I'm curious. How about this? Grab the first line from `ls -r /home/files/$DATE-*`. Then pass it to `rev | cut -d'-' -f1 | rev` or `awk -F'-' '{$NF=$NF+1; OFS="-"; print $0}'`.  Is it slower?

Comment: Using the output of `ls` is fragile as your solution will not work if there are files with whitespaces etc in it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [mktemp](http://man.cx/mktemp). It won't do exactly what you want, but it will guarantee that your directory names will be unique and you won't run into any sort of race conditions.

Comment: How should mktemp help here?

Comment: The OP want to create unique directories for storing files. (That's my understanding at least). Only `mktemp` is a safe way to guarantee directory uniqueness. You can incorporate the date as part of the `mktemp` directory name.

Comment: No, the OP wants the directory names following a scheme: `$DATE-$N`. A secure, stable solution would not follow this scheme, you are right with this. But however, there are situations, especially in GUI programs where this scheme makes sense because it is easily readable by humans.

Comment: This is correct I want directory names following a scheme ie DATE-1 DATE-2 etc and hek2mgl method worked perfectly for this.

Comment: No problem. By the time I saw the question, hek2mgi already posted their answer. I decided to mention `mktemp` because it gets around race conditions and other issues.